# How to pass External Data using inline nav in jqgrig?

Tags: jqgrid

I am use inline nav in jqgrid.
so i want to add new row.
when i add new row with this row data i want to pass some other external data.
How it is possible?

Comment: You should specify more clear which "external data" you need to use?

Comment: grid = $('#list') is my Grid. and i want to add new row using inline nav so i use inline nav in jqgrid.
when i add new row with this edirUrl i want pass Login person Id.

Comment: You wrote that you want **to pass some other external data** what you add new row with respect of `inlineNav`. My question was **which kind of external data you mean**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `addParams` property of the option of `inlineNav`. See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9565527/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10396691/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8551798/315935) for example.

**UPDATED**: Below is an example of the code:

```js
$("#list").jqGrid("inlineNav", "#pager", {
    addParams: {
        addRowParams: {
            keys: true,
            extraparam: {
                Patient_Id: function () {
                    return $("#sId").val();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am use first link u given.in this code when i save data i want to pass data like var Patient_Id=$(#sId).val();
so how to pass PatientId with my editurl:addMedicine.html

Comment: @AshuMehta: You can use for example `extraparam` parameter inside of `addParams` which defines `Patient_Id` property as function returned `$(#sId).val()`. See [the second link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10396691/315935) from my answer for the code example.

Comment: like this   extraparam: { retuen PatientId; }

Comment: @AshuMehta: NO! Like `extraparam: { Patient_Id: function () { return PatientId; }} `. Just see the code from [the second link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10396691/315935) and search for `extraparam` on the page.

Comment: In Inline nav as my previous Problem Plus '+' Can not be display

Comment: My code is J(#list).j('inlineNav',pager,{
addParams:{
positions:"afterSelected",
addRowParams:{},
extraparam:{
Patient_Id:funcation(){return PatientId;}
}
}
})

Comment: @AshuMehta: `extraparam` have to be the property of `addRowParams`. So `addRowParams:{}, extraparam: {...}` is wrong. Please, read [the code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10396691/315935) carefully. I updated my answer with the code example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19148/discussion-between-ashumehta-and-oleg)

Comment: extraparam is not work in addParams but its work only in EditParams

Comment: @AshuMehta: If you think that you found a bug in `inlineNav` you should demonstrate if on an test case. After that one will be able either reproduce the problem, find the bug in jqGrid and fix it or one will be able to find bug in your demo.

Comment: I am not sure but in addParams code somewhere  mastic by me
Thanks for help.