# How to sync inline and toolbar edit buttons in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jqgrid

How to sync jqgrid formatter actons and toolbar buttons:

1. If inline edit or add is started from formatter edit button or toolbar add or edit button ,
   other edit and add button sholt diabled and save and cancel enabled.
2. Save and cancel can be selected from toolbar or from formatter actions or using esc/enter

After that buttons shoud enabled/disabled properly.

Demo

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SendDataFromInlineNav.htm

from answer

[jqgrid, how to pass data when adding row using add navigator button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548328/jqgrid-how-to-pass-data-when-adding-row-using-add-navigator-button)

Does not work properly:

Clicking it edit action button does not enable toolbar cancel button.

Clicking in add or edit toolbar button does not disable edit action button.

How to sync those buttons properly ?