# How to disable save and cancel toolbar buttons in free jqgrid if line is not edited

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid does noes not disable inline toolbar save and cancel buttons sometimes.
Clicking in those buttons then causes exception because jqgrid code tries for find editable row id on click.

Inline save and cancel buttons in toolbar are active.
Clicking oth them causes javascript exception in jqgrid code.

How to disable/enable them properly ?

[jqgrid, how to pass data when adding row using add navigator button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548328/jqgrid-how-to-pass-data-when-adding-row-using-add-navigator-button) contains some code to do it manually. However jqgrid should handle this automaticlally and updateButtonState from this answer doesnt enable/disable have top toolbar actions buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem is the bug in free jqGrid. Just one symbol was missing (one dot) and so enabling/disabling worked wrong. I have fixed the bug (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/6e2517c6ffac469abf95fcbea6b34444e70df4ca)). Please reload the modified code of free jqGrid from the [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).